# Сортировка черезе operator.itemgetter

Tags: python, сортировка

Есть вот такой код:

```
tuples = [(1, 'd'), (2, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (3, 'c')] 
sorted(tuples, key=lambda x: x[1]) 

 ### [(4, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (1, 'd')]
```

Прочитал про то, что можно не использовать `lambda`-функцию, а воспользоваться `operator.itemgetter(n)`. Но в моём случае не совсем понимаю, что передать вместо `n`, чтобы получился такой же результат, как в первом примере? У меня сейчас вот такой пример и ошибка

```
import operator

tuples = [(1, 'd'), (2, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (3, 'c')] 
sorted(tuples, key=operator.getitem(1))
```

> TypeError: getitem expected 2 arguments, got 1

Что должно быть вторым аргументом у `getitem`?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ максимально прост - я невнимательный хлеб.
Вместо `getitem` нужно писать `itemgetter`

Comment: Невнимательный хлеб??))